# Issue with understanding how pointers and 'new' work

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm currently learning about pointers in my C++ book (Programming: Principles and Practice  using C++ by Stroustrup). The book had me do the following 'drill' to become accustom to pointers and arrays. I've commented parts of the drill that aren't relevant to my issue.

```
int num = 7;
int* p1 = &num;

// output p1 address and content...

int* p2 = new int(10);

// initialise each element, and output content...

int* p3 = p2;
p1 = p2;

// output p1 and p2 address and content...

delete[] p1;

/* As all pointers now point to the same array created in the free store, 
   I was under the impression that I only needed to use delete for 1 of 
   the pointers to deallocate memory,as above, but the program crashes 
   if I don't do it for all 3 and execute next section of code? */

p1 = new int(10);
p2 = new int(10);

// Initialise each array to a different range of numbers using a loop,
// output each array, change elements in p2 to be the same as p1, output...

delete[] p1;
delete[] p2;
```

The last part is where I am having trouble. When outputting each array, the elements values are the same. My guess is that p1 still == p2, due to the code a few lines before. I thought that when you use the 'new' keyword it returns an address, referencing a different, newly allocated block of memory and therefore p1 would no longer == p2. The only way I got it to work was to directly create 2 arrays and have p1 and p2 reference them using the & operator. Any explanation as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Without showing us how you initialize and output p1 and p2 (before making the values the same and output again), we can't know what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* p2 = new int(10);

// initialise each element, and output content...

int* p3 = p2;
p1 = p2;

// output p1 and p2 address and content...

delete[] p1;
```

This code leads to **undefined behavior**, because you allocate with `new` and free the memory with `delete[]`.

```
int* p2 = new int(10);
//allocates a single int with value 10
```

is different from

```
int* p2 = new int[10];
//allocates an uninitialized array of 10 ints
```

That aside (although a serious issue, as all undefined behavior), the problem was this:

```
int* p2 = new int(10);
int* p3 = p2;
p1 = p2;
//all pointer point to the same memory location

delete[] p1;
//delete that memory
//all three pointers are now invalid
```

Attempting to free the memory again via `delete p2` or `delete p3` will again lead to undefined behavior, and probably a crash, since you already deleted that memory. That is why allocating new memory will fix the crash.

Bottom line: don't free the same memory multiple times.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. I can't believe I missed the bracket mistake. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably stems from the fact that when you say

```
p = new int(10)
```

you are allocating just ONE integer and initializing it to 10, not an array of size 10.